# "This site can’t be reached" using Nginx as reverse proxy for Express Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, express, nginx

I am having trouble accessing my node server externally. Internally, I can access it fine, but I am unable to do so otherwise.

Here is my nginx configuration. I simply want to access my website using only my external IP (for example, 133.21.29.21)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 2500;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3005;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

server code

```
    app.server.listen(3003, "0.0.0.0", () => {
            console.log(app.server.address());
    });
```

I am running on port 3003 at the moment. I have tried sever nginx configurations and changing my server code as well (changing port, omitting "0.0.0.0", using "127.0.0.1") but I have not had any luck.

I've been trying to access my server by going to my-external-ip:2500, but i've tried accessing through other ports as well.

I've disable the ufw firewall and still have not had any luck. Curling locally works fine.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: try proxy_redirect http://localhost:3003 https://localhost; (you need to add http://)

Comment: @AbdulAhad in the location block or outside?

Comment: Like this?

`proxy_redirect http://localhost:3003/ http://localhost/;`

Comment: yeah, in the location block

Comment: Didn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Comment: I add a working nodejs file to an answer, you can cut/paste from there

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a proxy redirect

Take a look at the following example NGINX configuration file, the location / { } is pointing to a Node server on port 9080 and it works by navigating to https:// ... .com

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thedomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thedomain.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/thedomain.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/thedomain.error.log;

    server_name _;

    root            /var/www/html;

    index           index.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

    location /.well-known/ {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /jenkins {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout  90s;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://www.thedomain.com/jenkins;
    }

    location /wss/pforex {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:9190;

        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_read_timeout  90s;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:9190 https://www.thedomain.com/wss/pforex;
    }

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:9080;
        proxy_read_timeout  90s;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:9080 https://www.thedomain.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, proxy_redirect didn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: well, cut and paste from the working file.  you can use port 80 and remove the ssl stuff.  i've never tried it without DNS, that should be the only difference

Answer (score 0):

Nginx works as a front-end server, which in this case proxies the requests to a node.js server. Therefore you need to set up a Nginx config file for the node.

Create the file yourdomain.com at /etc/nginx/sites-available/:

```
# the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3003.
upstream app_yourdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3003; # can use localhost as well
    keepalive 8;
}

# the Nginx server instance
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.com.log;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
    # and much more can be added, see Nginx config options
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://app_yourdomain/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```

Besides you can even omit giving ip to `listen` method and it will take localhost by default

```
const app = express();

 app.listen(3003, () => {
        console.log(app.server.address());
 });
```

**If you are accessing the server directly with IP then you need to change**

```
server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;
```

with

```
server_name _;
```

Comment: Just tried it out and none of the sites could be accessed. I tried port visitng my-ip:3003, my-ip, my-ip:80, my-ip:2500;

Comment: Updating answer as you are directly accessing server with ip. With this config your app should be running on port 3003 and you can visit it on port 80

Comment: where this server is hosted? I mean have you exposed port 80 on your server?

Comment: Google cloud, and I've got the firewall (ufw) disabled right now, would it matter?

Comment: I am not sure about gcloud but make sure your ip is accesible for outer world in your vpc or load balance setting. you can search this for gcloud as this config is copied from my project which is currently running in production